# Using python import csv to populate data in MS Word template

Tags: python

I have a csv file with rows of data representing individual business info. Need to populate a word document template automatically from row and column in csv. Is there a python command function or library that does this?

Comment: `Need to populate a word document template automatically from row and column in csv` - what does it mean?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html You don't need extra library to work on csv file

Comment: Csv has lines of data, word doc has a location for the data ie Store Data = 765 in Word, with 765 coming from csv entry row for that store.  May be first data value in csv row.

Comment: I know how to output python values into csv. Now I need to get them into a word template - or even a table in word.

Comment: Do you want to form a table in a word document with contents from CSV files?

Answer (score 3):

There is a in-built Python library named `csv` which can be used to parse the CSV file. Then to write to a Word document you can use a library named `python-docx`. The following are the basic example for reading a CSV file and writing some data to Word Document.

READ CSV CODE: [source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print ', '.join(row)
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

WRITE TO WORD: [source](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)

p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
p.add_run(' and some ')
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

document.add_heading('Heading, level 1', level=1)
document.add_paragraph('Intense quote', style='Intense Quote')

document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in unordered list', style='List Bullet'
)
document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in ordered list', style='List Number'
)

document.add_picture('monty-truth.png', width=Inches(1.25))

records = (
    (3, '101', 'Spam'),
    (7, '422', 'Eggs'),
    (4, '631', 'Spam, spam, eggs, and spam')
)

table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Qty'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'Id'
hdr_cells[2].text = 'Desc'
for qty, id, desc in records:
    row_cells = table.add_row().cells
    row_cells[0].text = str(qty)
    row_cells[1].text = id
    row_cells[2].text = desc

document.add_page_break()

document.save('demo.docx')
```

Hope it helps